# AWS S3 - No CORS set but Amplify GET requests are working?

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, aws-amplify

I have an S3 bucket with no CORS configuration (it is empty) yet using AWS Amplify `Storage.get` i am able to successfully retrieve object URLs. I expected a 403 Forbidden response.

Confusingly, `Storage.list` does generate a 403 Forbidden response, as i would have expected.

**Code Sample 1 - CORS Not Set in S3 Bucket Permissions**

```
const URL = await Storage.get('file.jpg', {
    level: 'private',
    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
    expires: 5,
})
```

**Expected Result**: 403 Error, Forbidden. Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'destination_url' from origin 'source_url' has been blocked by CORS policy (beacuse the default is to deny cross origin requests unless a policy exists)

**Actual Result**: No error - `Amplify.get` returned a valid URL allowing access to file.jpg

**Code Sample 2 - CORS Not Set in S3 Bucket Permissions**

```
Storage.list('/', { level: 'private' })
.then(result => {
    // process response
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**Result is as expected**: 403 Error, Forbidden. Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'destination_url' from origin 'source_url' has been blocked by CORS policy

I can make Code Sample 2 work if i set CORS in the S3 Bucket Permissions.

What am i missing? I want CORS to apply to `Storage.get` requests.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you mean by *“does not work”*. Exactly what errors is the browser logging in the devtools console. Please edit/update the question itself to add those exact error messages, and to clearly state exactly what does not work: What did you expect to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: @Kevin did you solve this issue ?

Comment: @MadanBhandari Unfortunately not